# Is there anyway to do simple laravel notification

Tags: laravel, notifications

Is there anyway to make laravel notification in a simple way? I need to do notification function for my complaint handling system where the system should notify the user if complaint exist in their account which should be `User Id`.

Comment: Im stil looking for an answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a pusher like system with redis, node.js and socket.io

You have a [tutorial in Medium](https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d)